# ASP.NET Gridview's edit textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Can someone tell me how to retrieve the textbox within a gridview in asp.net c#? I have a bunch of data being displayed in a gridview and I want it to be editable. I have added a edit command field to it and it gives me this edit link. When I press this link, a textbox appears, but I how do I get the reference of that textbox so I can get whatever is inside the textbox and change it before calling the row update handler?

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accept if it work for you

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `FindControl` method to find the textbox you want......

in your rowedit event of gridview is

```
void AuthorsGridView_RowUpdating (Object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
  {
    // The GridView control does not automatically extract updated values 
    // from TemplateField column fields. These values must be added manually 
    // to the NewValues dictionary.

    // Get the GridViewRow object that represents the row being edited
    // from the Rows collection of the GridView control.
    int index = AuthorsGridView.EditIndex;
    GridViewRow row = AuthorsGridView.Rows[index];

    // Get the controls that contain the updated values. In this
    // example, the updated values are contained in the TextBox 
    // controls declared in the edit item templates of each TemplateField 
    // column fields in the GridView control.
    TextBox lastName = (TextBox)row.FindControl("LastNameTextBox");
    TextBox firstName = (TextBox)row.FindControl("FirstNameTextBox");


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access an element in a gridview by knowing the row that it resides within `RowIndex` and the element name `"text_textbox"`

```
TextBox text = ((TextBox)contacts.Rows[RowIndex].FindControl("text_textbox")).Text;
```